Laravel Testing with Multiple Databases: Preventing Migrations During Tests / Migrations failing
I'm working on a Laravel project that uses multiple MySQL databases. The main database (core_db) contains system tables like users, migrations, etc., while express_db and regio_db contain most of the other application tables. For testing, I'm using phpunit and pest, and I want to ensure that the tests run efficiently without unnecessary migrations. Even tho all migrations are already ran, Laravel is rerunning the migrations, and then its failing, because the main dbs are already up2date but Laravel is not recognizing it.
Here are the relevant configurations and files:
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\{RefreshDatabase, TestCase as BaseTestCase};
use Laravel\Telescope\Telescope;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication, RefreshDatabase;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        config()->set('audit.enabled', false);
        Telescope::stopRecording();
    }
}

phpunit.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/10.3/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="PULSE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="core_db_testing"/>
        <env name="DB_USERNAME" value="dbuser"/>
        <env name="DB_PASSWORD" value="test"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION_EXPRESS" value="mysql"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE_EXPRESS" value="express_db_testing"/>
        <env name="DB_USERNAME_EXPRESS" value="dbuser"/>
        <env name="DB_PASSWORD_EXPRESS" value="test"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION_REGIOANALYSIS" value="mysql"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE_REGIOANALYSIS" value="regio_db_testing"/>
        <env name="DB_USERNAME_REGIOANALYSIS" value="dbuser"/>
        <env name="DB_PASSWORD_REGIOANALYSIS" value="test"/>
        <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
    <source>
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </source>
</phpunit>

pest.php:
<?php

use App\Models\User;
use Laravel\Telescope\Telescope;


uses(Tests\TestCase::class)
    ->beforeEach(function () {
        Telescope::stopRecording();
    })
    ->in('Feature');


expect()->extend('toBeOne', function () {
    return $this->toBe(1);
});


.env.testing:
APP_ENV=testing

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=coreapi-mysql-1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=core_db_testing
DB_USERNAME=dbuser
DB_PASSWORD=test

DB_CONNECTION_EXPRESS=mysql
DB_HOST_EXPRESS=database-mysql-1
DB_PORT_EXPRESS=3306
DB_DATABASE_EXPRESS=express_db_testing
DB_USERNAME_EXPRESS=dbuser
DB_PASSWORD_EXPRESS=test

DB_CONNECTION_REGIOANALYSIS=mysql
DB_HOST_REGIOANALYSIS=database-mysql-1
DB_PORT_REGIOANALYSIS=3306
DB_DATABASE_REGIOANALYSIS=regio_db_testing
DB_USERNAME_REGIOANALYSIS=dbuser
DB_PASSWORD_REGIOANALYSIS=test

I'm running the tests using the following command:
sail artisan test --profile --stop-on-failure --exclude-group=brands_api --env=testing
Even though I use the RefreshDatabase trait, migrations are still being run during tests, causing them to fail. According to the Laravel documentation, RefreshDatabase should only migrate if the schema is out of date and otherwise just wrap each test in a transaction.
Same behaviour for DatabaseTransactions or DatabaseMigrations of course.
How can I ensure that migrations are only run if necessary and that the database state is correctly maintained for tests? Additionally, how can I prevent migrations from running every time if the schema is already up to date? What am I missing? Why is it re-running the migrations every time and cause the whole test to fail, since the migrations are already done?
The point is that, no matter what I do, the migrations are always executed again, although if I query them before test execution or look them up in the database, they are complete. But now it wants to run them again and maybe there are broken migrations - there are about 250 and I was not initially involved in the project, so they fail or the downs do not work properly. He therefore always tries to re-run migrations that have already been carried out...
Small excerpt from the error messages of the testings:
   FAILED  Tests\Feature\WebhookControllerTest > pipedrive webhook customer already exists                                                                                       QueryException   
  SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'client_id' (Connection: express, SQL: alter table `keywordgroups` add `client_id` int unsigned null after `title`)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:587
    583▕             $this->bindValues($statement, $this->prepareBindings($bindings));
    584▕ 
    585▕             $this->recordsHaveBeenModified();
    586▕ 
  ➜ 587▕             return $statement->execute();
    588▕         });
    589▕     }
    590▕ 
    591▕     /**

      +7 vendor frames 
  8   database/migrations/2021_03_26_125432_add_client_id_to_keywordgroups_table.php:16
      +36 vendor frames 
  45  tests/TestCase.php:14

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  
   FAILED  Tests\Feature\WebhookControllerTest > pipedrive webhook person                                                                                                        QueryException   
  SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'client_id' (Connection: express, SQL: alter table `keywordgroups` add `client_id` int unsigned null after `title`)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:587
    583▕             $this->bindValues($statement, $this->prepareBindings($bindings));
    584▕ 
    585▕             $this->recordsHaveBeenModified();
    586▕ 
  ➜ 587▕             return $statement->execute();
    588▕         });
    589▕     }
    590▕ 
    591▕     /**

      +7 vendor frames 
  8   database/migrations/2021_03_26_125432_add_client_id_to_keywordgroups_table.php:16
      +36 vendor frames 
  45  tests/TestCase.php:14

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  
   FAILED  Tests\Feature\WebhookControllerTest > pipedrive webhook person doesnt exist                                                                                           QueryException   
  SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'client_id' (Connection: express, SQL: alter table `keywordgroups` add `client_id` int unsigned null after `title`)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:587
    583▕             $this->bindValues($statement, $this->prepareBindings($bindings));
    584▕ 
    585▕             $this->recordsHaveBeenModified();
    586▕ 
  ➜ 587▕             return $statement->execute();
    588▕         });
    589▕     }
    590▕ 
    591▕     /**

      +7 vendor frames 
  8   database/migrations/2021_03_26_125432_add_client_id_to_keywordgroups_table.php:16
      +36 vendor frames 
  45  tests/TestCase.php:14

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  
   FAILED  Tests\Feature\WebhookControllerTest > pipedrive webhook unknown                                                                                                       QueryException   
  SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'client_id' (Connection: express, SQL: alter table `keywordgroups` add `client_id` int unsigned null after `title`)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:587
    583▕             $this->bindValues($statement, $this->prepareBindings($bindings));
    584▕ 
    585▕             $this->recordsHaveBeenModified();
    586▕ 
  ➜ 587▕             return $statement->execute();
    588▕         });
    589▕     }
    590▕ 
    591▕     /**

      +7 vendor frames 
  8   database/migrations/2021_03_26_125432_add_client_id_to_keywordgroups_table.php:16
      +36 vendor frames 
  45  tests/TestCase.php:14


  Tests:    54 failed, 1 passed, 12 pending (1 assertions)
  Duration: 31.97s


Can you provide the error you're getting from the --stop-on-failure?

I'd also like to see the diagnostic messages for "migrations are still being run during tests, causing them to fail."

@DishanSachin  I have added the requested error output to the initial question

@hakre I have added the requested error output to the initial question The point is that, no matter what I do, the migrations are always executed again, although if I query them before test execution or look them up in the database, they are complete. But now it wants to run them again and maybe there are broken migrations - there are about 250 and I was not initially involved in the project, so they fail or the downs do not work properly. He therefore always tries to re-run migrations that have already been carried out...

Hmm, RefreshDatabase should migrate fresh. I'd start with a make recipe first running the migrations with --drop for the test databases. afterwards they should be filled and you'd know if the sequence of all migrations is stable or not. Within in tests it's a bit more trickier. Add a simple database assertion that is counting for entries with a well known table not having too much data after migrations to keep things simple. What I don't know is how Laravel handles multiple databases with the same migrations, perhaps one of the DBs is expected to have a migrations table but not there?
